# Do websockets send and receive full messages?

Tags: javascript, python, django, websocket, django-channels

I am new to web development and I am trying to write a simple web game using python and [django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) for my server with some javascript for the front end graphics. I am using the [channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package to use websockets for the communication and I have a little question about websockets.

In python, I know that when we use sockets, the message isn't guaranteed to be sent fully. For example, if I use `socket.send` in python, I may not send the entire message and in that case I need to resend what is left, and on the receiving side, I am not guaranteed to get the full message using `socket.recv` (assuming the `bufsize` argument is big enough for the full message), so I have to keep calling `recv` until I get the entire message.

**My question is: Is it the same with websockets or not?**

I tried looking for this in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) docummentation and in google, but I couldn't find any information on this. In addition, every example I have seen online didn't take this into account, so it seems like what I send with `socket.send` (in javascript) is exactly what I get on the other end and vice versa.

Is it true? Can I assume that the message I send with `socket.send` on the client side will be received fully in one event on the server side (which in my case is a [websocket consumer](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html#websocketconsumer)) and the other way around: if the server sends a message to the client, will it be received fully in one `Message` event on the client side in javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Websocket is a level of abstraction above sockets just like HTTP. They should already take care of sending the chunks until the full message is sent and as well in the receiving side. Just like you do not worry about this while using a regular HTTP client or server, you shouldn't also worry about that since the underlying websocket client should do that

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the message will be received if the client is connected. And visa versa, that the server will receive the message it is listening.

Django Channel's are reliably unreliable.

`Calling receive on these channels does not guarantee that you will get the messages in order or that you will get anything if the channel is non-empty.`

https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/channel_layer_spec.html#channel-semantics

Comment: But if the connection is stable, am I guaranteed to receive the entire message in one go. For example, if I do `socket.send("Hello There")`, can I be sure that the entire message was sent fully and that it will be received fully on the other end, or do I need to use some buffering techniques or something like that to ensure everything is sent and received correctly?